# Surface Pro Reinstall Always Ends up as Education Edition

Tags: windows, installation, reinstall, version

I have a surface pro 7+ supplied by my uni. As default it came with windows 10 Education, which forces me to link it to my Uni account. However by doing this, it becomes unusable off campus - it retains loads of links to uni servers etc, which aren't accessible off site, which leads to constant pauses while those connections time out.

No problem, I thought I'd just reinstall vanilla windows - according to ShowKey the machine has an OEM windows 10 Pro license. I grabbed the win 10 media creation tool, created a USB key, and installed - but still ended up with the education edition after install. I then added ei.cfg, and set it up as:

[Channel]
_Default
[VL]
0

This time I was prompted to choose the edition during setup. I chose pro, but I still ended up with the education edition. I then set up ei.cfg as:

[EditionID]
Professional
[Channel]
OEM
[VL]
0

And also created a PID.txt with the product code that ShowKey tells me is my OEM Windows 10 Pro key, but again I ended up with the Education edition.

So where is this decision to install the education version coming from? Why when I explicitly select Pro, do I always end up with Education?

Comment: The PID itself is coming from the computers UEFI firmware.  Modern computers that ship with windows have the key embedded in the firmware.  You created PID.txt but did you create the matching ei.cfg to go with it?  I myself don't have a machine like this but I can tell that either windows didn't find your PID.txt or didn't accept it because there was no ei.cfg to go with it.

Comment: The college still owns this computer, according to Microsoft. If the college sold the compute they should have decommissioned it, but you may need to buy and install your own Windows license.